# MBP 2009 does not detect new Internal SSD disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, sata

I have a Macbook Pro - Mid 2009 - 15"

I bought a new SSD (Crucial) to replace the SATA Internal Disk. Problem is that the computer does not detect new  Internal SSD disk.

The first thing I did was to format the new SSD as: Mac OS Plus (registered) with Utility Disk app with a MBP 2014

This is what I tried so far with cero results:

Once I install the new physical SSD disk:

- I can not reboot the computer from a USB booteable pen with the shorcut [POWER BUTTON + ALT]. I get a flashing folder with a question mark in the screen.
- I can not reboot the computer with the shorcut [COMMAND BUTTON + R] to star from the Recovery Mode. I get a flashing folder with a question mark in the screen.
- I also tried with [COMMAND BUTTON + R] with the computer connected to Internet by cable. I get a flashing folder with a question mark in the screen.

Then I tried this:

- I connected the new SSD to other computer (MBP 2014), here I am able to access the disk with no problem, write it, etc. No problem at all. This means to me that the disk has no problem.
- I put the old disk back into my MBP 2009. I worked fine. This means to me that the connector cable to the SATA Disk is fine.
- If I connect the new SSD via USB wire to the the MBP 2009 I have no problem to access and write the new disk. This means to me that the format of the new SSD is compatbible with the MBP 2009.

I tried two SSD disk far: Crucial 120GB and Kingston 120GB. But it didn't make any difference. Same problem in both disks.

This is driving me crazy. I installed a lot of disks in my computer and this is the first time I can not get it.

What else can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: It can’t start up from Recovery because there’s no Recovery partition yet. It’s too old to be able to use Internet Recovery. It should be able to boot from USB, hold opt at boot not power/opt. Test the USB on another Mac too.

Comment: @Tetsujin Can I create a partition in the new SSD and do whatever I need to do in the partition to start up from Recovery with [CMD + R]? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: The Recovery Partition is created as you install the OS onto the drive… that's why you need to get the USB working. Test on another Mac to see if you got the format etc correct. See https://support.apple.com/HT201372

Comment: @Tetsujin ok. Should I choose a certain version for 2009 MBP?: El Capitan, Sierra...

Comment: El Cap is the last OS that machine can run.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you very much. I've got it!